# Android: use so files from other project

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I try to use external sdk which include jar file and some *.so files. Also have sample project from eclipse which include same files in it. When I import project into android studio it works fine but when I tried to copy *.so files from imported project to my current project it cause error `UnsatisfiedLinkError`

Sample project target api 14, mine project target api 27. Should I inlude ndk support to my current project and recompile this *.so files or maybe is any option to use old files from sample?

Comment: You try to call a native method from your kotlin code, and expect that the implementation in the external so file will be called? It won't, because the names are different

Comment: @AlexCohn nope. I don't use directly methods from native code but library which I used need this files to works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.create a folder named `jniLibs` under `main` folder, the structure is like below fig.

```
 |–app:
    |–|–src:
    |–|–|–main
    |–|–|–|–jniLibs
    |–|–|–|–|–armeabi
    |–|–|–|–|–|–.so Files
    |–|–|–|–|–x86
    |–|–|–|–|–|–.so Files
    ...
    |–|–|–|–|–other abi folder such as armeabi-v7a
    |–|–|–|–|–|–.so Files
```

2. place .jar file in project `libs` folder and add below line in `module` build.gradle file

   dependencies {
          implementation files('libs/your_own.jar')
       }

All should be ok.

**Edited:**
some of android devices(emulator) has 64-bit processors, if your jinLibs hasn't `arm64` subfolder, you could add this filters(abiFilters) to your app module’s build.gradle files:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
    }

}
```

this will tell app only use .so files in existing folders.

Comment: That's the way how I try to figure out before but not working. Structure which you post here is like in sample project after import to android studio from eclipse project. After create same in my current project I have error which I mentioned above :(

Comment: thanks, that fixed my problem, `so` files from sample has only armeabi version but works fine on my phone. But in my current project I need to specify ndk configuration which you post here to works in same device, strange for me :/